# Splitting polygons and getting areas to split also

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I have been provided with a shapefile with certain land areas to split. How do I split the polygons so that the new areas are calculated and are listed in the attribute table? Currently I've been able to split the polygons but the area for each part is still listed at the same area of the original polygon in the attribute table before it was split.

Comment: Open attribute table, right click on area field header and choose calculate geometry to update and overwrite values in field.

Comment: An area attribute is just an attribute. If you want it changed after an operation, you need to change it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file geodatabase, then import your shapefile into the created file geodatabase and the `Shape_Area` will be calculated automatically for you.

Here is a quote from the deprecated [Calculate Area](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/calculate-areas.htm) tool which states that shape_area is calculated automatically if you are using geodatabase feature class:

> Because there are easier and more efficient ways to get the area of
>   features, the Calculate Areas tool has been deprecated. Use the
>   Calculate Field tool or the Geometry Calculator instead of the
>   Calculate Areas tool in your workflows and custom script or models
>   tools. **If you are using feature classes in a geodatabase**, **the**
>   **shape_area attribute field is maintained for you automatically**.

Example:

An area of a polygon before split

[image]

The areas of polygons after split

[image]

Once I select finish sketch the Shape_Area was updated (recalculated) automatically.

If you want to keep using shapefile, then you need to use Calculate Geometry to calculate the area manually.